# efficient line parsing method in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, line

I want to parse files containing lines like this:

```
funcName(param1=value1, param2=value2,...)
```

For each line, I want all the values for all parameters. So I repeatedly call get(const char* param, char *value) for all params. My get function works like this:

```
//given const char* param, get char* value
find first "="
get the string between "(" and this "=" or "," and "="
remove extra spaces
if the string is equal to param,
    set value to the string between "=" and ","
    remove extra spaces of string value
else
    move to next "=" and repeat the process
```

**But** this method is **not efficient**. It is very time consuming. Because every time I find a parameter, it searches from the beginning of the line. So how can I find all the values for all the parameters in an efficient way in C++?

Comment: Well, parse the line once to get all parameter names, then repeatedly call your get function.

Comment: @Tarik That's the approach adopted in existing method. I mean, for one line, how to improve the performance?

Comment: [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) in conjunction with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) comes in handy.

Comment: parse the complete file once, create a map for each params as key. Use that map to search for keys, searching in map is of order log(n).

Comment: I'd do a state machine so I can pass through the line once - when I see a "(" I know I have to start looking for parameters. When I see a "=" I know I've finished with the name and have to collect the value. When I see a "," or a ")" I know I have a name/value pair that  I can process. Add in a bit of whitespace handling and you're done.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've read some pages related to getline() and istringstream(), still unders study.

Comment: @danishansari This task has to be finished line by line. Because for one parameter, there could be different values in different lines.

Comment: @dudu Read further ... I gave you some useful links.